# How to display pop up div for dynamically created database elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a grid of 40 thumbnails of staff images and I'd like to display additional text (mainly their biography) when the user hovers over each element.

I've tried using Jquery PowerTip (http://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/) which does the job, but I don't know how to dynamically create each tooltip to connect to each thumbnail.

My Javascript skills are quite poor, so I'm hoping someone can show me how to simply display a pop up div unique to each person on hover next to each item?

```
<div class="people-list-container">
<ul class="people-list">

<a href="/Person/Details/8045">
    <li>
        <img src="8045.jpg" class="img-polaroid" />
        Bob Smith                                   
        <br />
        Australia
    </li>
</a>

<a href="/Person/Details/8046">
    <li>
        <img src="8046.jpg" class="img-polaroid" />
        Jill Jane                                   
        <br />
        Australia
    </li>
</a>

<a href="/Person/Details/8047">
    <li>
        <img src="8047.jpg" class="img-polaroid" />
        John Doe                                   
        <br />
        Australia
    </li>
</a>    

// ETC ETC

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: something like the glossary in [*THIS FIDDLE*](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/y4HCw/)?  you only need css

Comment: the docs for PowerTip show: http://jsfiddle.net/stevenbenner/2baqv/  The javascript, css, html, and live page view are all in panes for easy viewing.

Comment: Just a FYI, your markup is invalid. The only element you should have inside `UL` is an `LI` (or scripting elements).

Comment: Thanks Hugo, I'll fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working fiddle with your code... hover on images to see the tooltip

the jquery function cycle each element with class img-polaroid and then set the title that will be displayed as popup by powerTip function.

http://jsfiddle.net/9tcTx/1/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".img-polaroid").each(function(index,element){
        $(element).attr('title','element at ' + index);
        $(element).powerTip({
            placement: 'se' // north-east tooltip position
        });;
    });
});
```

html

```
<div class="people-list-container">
<ul class="people-list">

<a href="/Person/Details/8045">
    <li>
        <img src="8045.jpg" class="img-polaroid" />
        Bob Smith                                   
        <br />
        Australia
    </li>
</a>

<a href="/Person/Details/8046">
    <li>
        <img src="8046.jpg" class="img-polaroid" />
        Jill Jane                                   
        <br />
        Australia
    </li>
</a>

<a href="/Person/Details/8047">
    <li>
        <img src="8047.jpg" class="img-polaroid" />
        John Doe                                   
        <br />
        Australia
    </li>
</a>    

// ETC ETC

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: THanks, great response as it also gives me some of the nice features of powertip

Answer (score 1):

No Javascript needed. Try something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="person_info">
    <a href="#">
      Person info blablabla
      <span class="tip"> tip content </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="person_info">
    <a href="#">
      Person info blablabla
      <span class="tip"> tip content </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="person_info">
    <a href="#">
      Person info blablabla
      <span class="tip"> tip content </span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then with css:

```
.person_info             { position: relative;}
.tip                     {display: none; position: absolute; left: 100%;}
.person_info:hover .tip  {display: block}
```

Comment: Good response, I prefer the powertip option as it gives me some nice additional features, but this is a good css only approach

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a Javascript process for that.

How do you build your page? is it a static page ? or dynamic ? 
if it is dynamic, I assume that you already have a javascript function for that.

Just add for each element a call like described in document :

```
$('#element').data('powertip', 'This will be the <b>tooltip text</b>.');
```

Comment: you don't "need" javascript. css will do it just fine

Comment: Nice Solution that you offer. +1

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerTip you need to include the text you want included as your tooltip in the 'title' attribute:

```
<img src="8045.jpg" id="imageid" class="img-polaroid" title="Your Tooltip Text Here" />
```

Then in your javascript:

```
$('#imageid').powerTip({
    placement: 'n',
    smartPlacement: true
});
```

Which will place it directly above the image.  Note that you will need to include the PowerTip javascript file on your page.